# Is sched_getcpu() reliable on Linux?

Tags: linux, pthreads, scheduling, affinity

I'm trying to debug some performance issues with pthreads on Linux and I think [sched_getcpu()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sched_getcpu) may be lying to me. It reports a constant CPU for each thread, whereas profiling experiments seem to suggest the threads are actually migrating from one core to another during their life-time.

I wonder if `sched_cpu()` just reports the first CPU that the thread started running on, and is oblivious to thread migration ? Has anyone else noticed this, or seen any evidence that the the return value of `sched_getcpu()` might change ? If it's not realiable, are there any other methods for tracking current CPU (use `CPUID` maybe ?) ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getcpu.2.html indicates sched_getcpu() is just a wrapper for getcpu().

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getcpu.2.html suggests that the information provided is accurate, because an old caching option is no longer used:

> The tcache argument is unused since Linux 2.6.24...it specified a
>   pointer to a caller-allocated buffer in thread-local storage that was
>   used to provide a caching mechanism for getcpu().  Use of the cache
>   could speed getcpu() calls, at the cost that there was a very small
>   chance that the returned information would be out of date. The caching
>   mechanism was considered to cause problems when migrating threads
>   between CPUs, and so the argument is now ignored.

So unless you are using a pre-2.6.24 kernel it seems unlikely you could be seeing old/cached information.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer - my kernel version appears to be 3.10 so it sounds like I should not be seeing this behaviour. I'll have to dig a little deeper...

Answer (score 1):

Calling sched_getcpu has two problems:

1. It only tells you where the thread is running when it executes the call,
2. Calling a system routine could cause a thread to migrate.

If you are using Intel runtime you could set KMP_AFFINITY=verbose as it will provide the same information (formatted differently) on stderr when the program executes its first parallel section.